ESP32 FFT I'm not getting the correct max frequency of the input signal
I'm working on a project on my ESP32s3, trying to correctly evaluate the maximum frequency of an input signal. I've performed my fft basing my code on the FFT dsp example on ESP-IDF.
Actually I generate the signal inside my code, sampling it at a very high frequency. The signal i generate has his peak frequency at 5Hz, but the code I wrote gives back values way higher than this peak frequency.
It might be important to mention that the Default fft size that i'm using is 4096.
This is the code that i use to generate the signal
double composite_signal(double t, SignalComponent *component) {
    double signal = 0;
    
    // Summing sine components
    for (int i = 0; i < component->num_sin_components; i++) {
        signal += component->sin_amplitudes[i] * sin(2 * M_PI * component->sin_frequencies[i] * t);
    }
    
    return signal;
}

SignalComponent component = {
    2, // Number of sine components
    {3,5}, // Sine frequencies in HZ
    {2,4} // Sine amplitudes
};

//AND IN THE MAIN
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_SAMPLES; i++) {
        double t = (double)i / SAMPLING_RATE;
        wave[i] = composite_signal(t, &component);
        //ESP_LOGI(TAG, "FFT for %f ", wave[i]);
    }

Those are the rates i'm using

#define SAMPLING_RATE 1000 // Hz
#define DURATION 3 // seconds
#define NUM_SAMPLES (SAMPLING_RATE * DURATION)
#define TH 3 //threshold for magnitude, max frequency of the fft

Then I process the FFT as it is done in the dsp ESP IDF example
dsps_wind_hann_f32(wind, NUM_SAMPLES);
    // Generate input signal for x1 A=1 , F=0.1
    // dsps_tone_gen_f32(x1, N, 1.0, 0.1,  0);
    // for(int i=0; i<N;i++){
    //     ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Signal at index %i is %f", i, x1[i]);
    // }

    // Generate input signal for x2 A=0.1,F=0.2
    //dsps_tone_gen_f32(x2, N, 0.1, 0.2, 0);

    // Convert two input vectors to one complex vector
    for (int i = 0 ; i < NUM_SAMPLES ; i++) {
        y_cf[i * 2] = wave[i] * wind[i];
        y_cf[i * 2 + 1] = 0; // I don't have a second vector as in the example
    }
    // FFT
    unsigned int start_b = dsp_get_cpu_cycle_count();
    dsps_fft2r_fc32(y_cf, NUM_SAMPLES);
    unsigned int end_b = dsp_get_cpu_cycle_count();
    // Bit reverse
    dsps_bit_rev_fc32(y_cf, NUM_SAMPLES);
    // Convert one complex vector to two complex vectors
    dsps_cplx2reC_fc32(y_cf, NUM_SAMPLES);

    //RETRIEVE THE MAX FREQ OF THE SIGNAL
    int maxI = 0;
    double maxM = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_SAMPLES; i++)
    {
        if(y_cf[i]>TH && y_cf[i]>maxM){
            maxI = i;
            maxM = y_cf[i];
        }
    }
    ESP_LOGI(TAG, "THE MAX Index is %i", maxI);
    float maxF = maxI;
    maxF *= SAMPLING_RATE / (float) NUM_SAMPLES; //max frequency retrival

Then the example code does some adjustment in order to display the signals correctly.
Obviously here I'm expecting that the max frequency should be something around 5Hz. But in the output I'm getting:
I (22594) main: THE MAX Index is 1838
I (22944) main: The maximum frequency of the signal is 612.666687, and the relative magnitude value is 564.219421.
I've been following various guides and I think that is the proper way to get the max frequency.
Can somebody tell me what I'm doing wrong ?

Why are you over-sampling so heavily? With a max frequency component of 5 Hz, you only need to sample at 10-20 Hz. Second, is the FFT routine you're using expecting the signal input to be real or complex? I see the 'fft2r' in the function name and I would assume the 'r' stands for real. You, however, are passing complex data. If it is supposed to be real, you're passing a signal with zeroes in every other position. The output will not be correct.

I based myself on this example: link . The example feeds in input a complex array made from two real arrays, since I only have one real array I just left the imaginary part as zero.
I'm sampling at a very high rate because I want to be able to handle also higher frequencies for the input signal.

The documentation for the library shows a call to an initialization function that initializes some tables for the FFT (dsps_fft2r_init_fc32). I don't see that call in your code.

I did not past here the full code, but the initialization is done as in the example:
esp_err_t ret;     ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Start Example.");     ret = dsps_fft2r_init_fc32(NULL, CONFIG_DSP_MAX_FFT_SIZE);     if (ret  != ESP_OK)     {         ESP_LOGE(TAG, "Not possible to initialize FFT. Error = %i", ret);         return;     }

I eventually found out that the FFT needs in input an array of a dimension that has to be expressible as a power of 2.
